# Unable to search character with string input from fgets

Tags: c, char, fgets, gets

I'm writing a program to find the location of a certain character in a string using `strchr`. When using `fgets` to input the string from the user, the program does not execute properly.

However when using `gets` everything works fine.

Code that works using `gets()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char let;
    char input[50];
    char *ptr;
    printf("what is the string that you would like to check?\n");
    gets(input);
    printf("what is the character that you would like to find?\n");
    let = getchar();
    printf("in string \"%s\"...\n", input);
    ptr = strchr(input, let);
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("the letter %c was found at character %d\n", let, ptr - input + 1);
        ptr = strchr(ptr + 1, let);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
what is the string that you would like to check?
what is the character that you would like to find?
in string "why is the world when wondering"...
the letter w was found at character 1
the letter w was found at character 12
the letter w was found at character 18
the letter w was found at character 23
```

Code that does not work usgin `fgets()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char let;
    char input[50];
    char *ptr;
    printf("what is the string that you would like to check?\n");
    fgets(input, 16, stdin);
    printf("what is the character that you would like to find?\n");
    let = getchar();
    printf("in string \"%s\"...\n", input);
    ptr = strchr(input, let);
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("the character is found at %d \n", ptr - input + 1);
        ptr = strchr(ptr + 1, let);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
what is the string that you would like to check?
what is the character that you would like to find?
in string "abcdefghijklmno"...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
fgets(input, 16, stdin)
```

to

```
fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)
```

When you pass an argument of `16` to `fgets()` you are instructing it to read *no more than 15 characters*. Why?

From the `fgets()` manpage:

> fgets()  reads in *at most one less than* size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.

If you provide *more than `size -1` characters*, the remaining characters are *left in the input buffer*.

Then when the program subsequently calls

```
let = getchar();
```

`let` is assigned whatever the next character in the input buffer is - without even waiting for you to type anything else. It then searches for this character in the string you provided - but in the example you provided doesn't find it.

Comment: You might add that in `printf("the character is found at %d \n", ptr - input + 1);` the conversion specification `%d` is inappropriate for the difference of 2 pointers, either use `%td` or cast the difference as `(int)` for a more portable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet the call

```
gets (input);
```

does not restrict the number of characters the user can input. Take into account that the function `gets` is not supported by the C Standard and is unsafe.

In the second code snippet you declared the variable `input` as

```
char input[50];
```

So it is more natural to call `fgets` the following way

```
fgets (input,sizeof( input ),stdin );
```

instead of

```
fgets (input,16,stdin);
```

The standard function `getchar` reads any character including white spaces.

So instead it it is much better to use

```
scanf( " %c", &let );
```

Otherwise `getchar` can read any character (including for example the new line character) leaved in the input buffer. While the call of `scanf` will skip any white space character.